# Laravel middleware parameter inside a middleware group

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a middleware added in the middleware group `web` which is used in my routes like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { // }
```

This web group includes multiple middleware which will be used to all routes inside the route group.
I am setting these middleware like this

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\FeatureFlags::class
        ]
    ];
```

My problem here is in the `FeatureFlag` middleware, I want to pass a third parameter `feature`. Since the `FeatureFlag` parameter is initiated inside the `web` group, I have no idea how to pass the third parameter.

Comment: where do you want to pass third parameter?

Comment: i want to get the type of `feature` from the route which is inside the `web` middleware

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to list your middleware in `$routeMiddleware` and then use it with a parameter in a middleware group

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'flags:feature',
    ]
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'flags' => \App\Http\Middleware\FeatureFlags::class,
];
```